# How to implement this keyword in main class?

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, this, nfc

I need help implementing the following directions. I know I have to make a constructor, but where do I put the constructor? And can I implement both main and Mylistener in the same class?

Here are the directions I have to do:

Now you are ready to use our API in your Maven Project.
Next step would be to implement a BeamReceiveListener like this:

```
public class MyListener implements BeamReceiveListener {
    public void beamRecieved(NdefMessage message) {
        // handle the message here
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize your NFC Reader and start the Android Beam Handshake.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NFCDevice device = NFCDeviceFactory
            .createNFCDevice(NFCDeviceType.AUTODETECT);
    device.setBeamReceiveListener(this);
    device.initalizeWithDefaultValues();
    device.start();  // the device will whait for the Android Device now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the constructor inside the MyListener class.  Yes, you can implement main and MyListener in the same class.  You can even implement MyListener in main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
NFCDevice device = NFCDeviceFactory
        .createNFCDevice(NFCDeviceType.AUTODETECT);
       class MyListener implements BeamReceiveListener {
       MyListener(){} //constructor

       public void beamRecieved(NdefMessage message) {
            // handle the message here
       }
 }
device.setBeamReceiveListener(new MyListener());
device.initalizeWithDefaultValues();
device.start();  // the device will whait for the Android Device now
```

}

Comment: dear downvoter, please explain the issue with this answer. It looks reasonable to me